# Methods for solving multivariable system of linear inequalities

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I'm looking for a way to solve multivariable system of linear inequalities.
The systems I'm trying to solve have more that 6 unknowns and I'm interested in all the intervals that are solutions.
I found about Fourier–Motzkin elimination, is there any other methods that can be used to solve such systems?

Comment: Please define "solve".

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Just normal inequalities: for each unknown find all numbers for which the inequalities are true, the values for each unknown described by intervals.

Comment: In other words, your system of inequalities defines a polytope and you want to find the smallest bounding box for this polytope, one that can be described using Cartesian products, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think the system of inequalities will create polytope (for N-variables in N-dimentional space) and the space where they all overlap will be the solution to all the inequalities.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Here is example system of inequalities and the solution in interval notation:

$$
x + y - z > 60  \\
10x - 2y + 5z < 120  \\
-x + y + z > 30  \\
$$

$$
x \in (19, ∞)\\
y \in ((15 (x + 2))/7, ∞)\\

z \in (x - y + 30, -2/5 (5 x - y - 60))  \\

$$

I want a method to get the solution of a system like this but with more unknown variables.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No, I was reading on linear programming and how to find the region that contains solutions to all inequalities. I can use the simplex algorithm to find the minimum or maximum of a function but I don't have one and I'm stuck.

Comment: Suppose you have the triangle defined by $$x + y \leq 1,  \qquad x \geq 0, \qquad y \geq 0$$ How would you solve this? By obtaining the minimal bounding box $[0,1] \times [0,1]$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Is there method for finding the bounding box? This will work only if all the unknowns have greater than or less that constraint right? I see that not all points in the bounding box are solutions for example:
$$
x = 0.75\\
y = 0.75\\
$$

Comment: Take the triangle and project it onto the $x$-axis and then onto the $y$-axis. The Cartesian product of those two intervals is the minimal bounding box, which can be found via linear programming. Of course, there will be points in the minimal bounding box that are not in the triangle. However, the minimal bounding box is the Cartesian product that contains the triangle and whose area is minimal. Since it seems to me that you dislike that, I suspect you are looking for something other than a minimal bounding box.